# Incompatibility Issue in upgrade django from 2.4 to 3.0

Tags: python, django

I maintain a system and update it frequently because it's been used a lot since django 1.8, currently the project is on django 2.2.4 and I'd like to upgrade to 3.0, however, I'm having a model compatibility issue.

The "models" are in simplified versions and this works normally in previous versions. The "models" are that way because I migrated a giant system so I made the database as close as possible to the old one to save me work.

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    idPessoa=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="nome")
    address=models.TextField('endereço',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True)

class Bancos(Pessoa):
    @property
    def idBanco(self):
        return self.idPessoa
    @idBanco.setter
    def idBancoSetter(self,valor):
        self.idPessoa = valor
    codigo_febraban=models.CharField(max_length=5,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ContasBancariasPessoas(models.Model):
    idContaBancaria = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    idPessoa = models.ForeignKey(Pessoas,limit_choices_to={'visivel':True},on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='idPessoa',verbose_name='titular')
    idBanco = models.ForeignKey(Bancos,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='idPessoa',verbose_name="banco",
                                related_name='bancos',null=True)
    Agencia = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,default='0000',
                               verbose_name="agência")
    Numero = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False,default='0000',
                              verbose_name='número da conta')
    Titular = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True,
                               verbose_name='titular',help_text="nome que é exibido na conta")
```

The error is the following:
**django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'institucional.ContasBancariasPessoas.idBanco' refers to field 'idPessoa' which is not local to model 'institucional.Bancos'**

Comment: At a guess, `to_field='idPessoa'` in the problematic line should become `to_field='idBanco'`.

Comment: There is no Django 2.4.

Comment: Django 2.4 [never existed](https://pypi.org/project/Django/#history). The lastest release to-date of Django 2.x is 2.2.24. Do you mean Django 2.2.4, Python 2.4, or something of the likes?

Comment: "At a guess, to_field='idPessoa' in the problematic line should become to_field='idBanco'."  There no field "idBanco" in the model, the model "Bancos" is a child from "Pessoas" so it has the field 'idPessoa'